# No Result on pyodbc query

Tags: python, tkinter, pyodbc

I have resolved some issues with this script but this one is currently stopping me dead in my tracks. It doesn't even return an error anymore, and from what I gather, it should work, im at that "This shouldn't happen" stage. I am quite new to python but learning everyday, can't wait to have this downpath to create awesome things!

I was also getting the same error without fselemptext = ("'" + selemptext + "'"), usually you need the quote on MSSQL, I was gessing I needed to add them here as well. If I take the query as is and replace the ? by 'username' it works flawlessly.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd

root = Tk()
root.title('ONE')
root.iconbitmap('Y:\APPLICATIONS\ICONS\ONE_icon.ico')
root.geometry("1700x1000")
frm = Frame(root)

server = 'GDLAP009'
database = 'cwwebapp_gdl'
username = 'reporting'
password = '########'

conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';    DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
c = conn.cursor()
query = ("""    SELECT 
                Time_Sheet.Time_Sheet_RecID, 
                Time_Sheet.TE_Period_RecID, 
                TE_Period.Period, 
                TE_Period.Date_Start, 
                TE_Period.Date_End, 
                Time_Sheet.Member_RecID, 
                Time_Sheet.TE_Status_ID,
                Member.Member_ID
                FROM Time_Sheet
                INNER JOIN Member ON Time_Sheet.Member_RecID = Member.Member_RecID 
                INNER JOIN TE_Status ON Time_Sheet.TE_Status_ID = TE_Status.TE_Status_ID 
                INNER JOIN TE_Period ON Time_Sheet.TE_Period_RecID = TE_Period.TE_Period_RecID 
                WHERE Member.Member_ID LIKE ? """)

def searchemp():
    c.execute(query, (fselemptext))
    erecords = c.fetchall()
    c.close()
    return erecords
    for record in erecords:
        tv.insert('', 'end', values=record)

yoptions = ["2016", "2017", "2018", "2019", "2020"]

clky_b = StringVar()
clky_b.set(yoptions[4])

drpy_l = Label(root, text="Select Year")
drpy_l.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=20, pady=10)
drpy_b = OptionMenu(root, clky_b, *yoptions)
drpy_b.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=20, pady=10, columnspan=2)

emptext = StringVar()
sele_l = Label(root, text="Select Employee")
sele_l.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=10)
sele_e = Entry(root, width=30, textvariable=emptext)
sele_e.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=20, pady=10)
emptext.set("Default Value")
selemptext = emptext.get()
fselemptext = ("'" + selemptext + "'")

runq_b = Button(root, text="Run Query", command=searchemp)
runq_b.grid(row=0, column=5, columnspan=2, padx=20, pady=10, ipadx=100)

frm.grid(row=50, column=0, padx=20, columnspan=8)
tv = ttk.Treeview(frm, columns=(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8), show="headings", height="45")
tv.pack()
tv.heading(1, text="Name")
tv.heading(2, text="Time")
tv.heading(3, text="Test1")
tv.heading(4, text="Test2")
tv.heading(5, text="Test3")
tv.heading(6, text="Test4")
tv.heading(7, text="Test5")
tv.heading(8, text="Test6")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: ```for record in erecords:``` This loop will never get executed due to ```return erecords```

Comment: I'm sorry, that was commented, forgot to do so again, even without it however, it does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a several problems in your code:

- You're getting the value from the entry about a millisecond after creating the entry. The user won't have had a chance to type anything. You need to call the `get` method at the point that you need the data.
- When using a parameterized query you do not need to quote the values.
- You need to pass a tuple to the `execute` method. `(fselemptext)` is not a tuple. `(fselemptext,)` is a tuple.
- You have a `return` statement in the middle of your `searchemp` function, which will prevent any further code from being executed. You need to remove that `return` statement.
- You probably shouldn't call c.close(). It's very odd to create a cursor in one scope and close it in another. Putting that in the function will prevent the function from working a second time. Either remove it, or have the function create and then close its own cursor.

You can wrap all of those changes into your `searchemp` function:

```
def searchemp():
    selemptext = emptext.get()
    c.execute(query, (fselemptext,))
    erecords = c.fetchall()

    for record in erecords:
        tv.insert('', 'end', values=record)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!
Using the get() function does indeed fix the issue! I will fix the other issues as well!